# Can't login to dashboard after setting cookie to root?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

After i set cookie to root as default i can't login to dashboard it's just redirects me to login page, i can only if i remove it..

I set this inside wp-config.php

```
define('SITECOOKIEPATH','/');
```

Also same issue is when i install **root cookie** plugin.

Path looks like this:

```
 public_html    
   account
     wp-config.php
     wp-load.php //etc all wordpress stuffs..   
   application
     model
     view
     controller   
   system   
   assets
```

Comment: did you clear your cookies?

Comment: Yes, but it just redirects me to login.. Looks like i have not administrator privilegius, but i have because it works when i remove this code from wp-config.php... And in database is a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} as wp_capabilities and user_level 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root of the problem seems to be wrong-domain url and cookies. But there's bunch of stuff that might go wrong. Usually is this, so try this solution.

On the Settings->General screen in a single site installation of WordPress, there are two fields named "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)". They are important settings, since they control where WordPress thinks your site is located. They control the display of the URL in the admin section of your page, as well as the front end, and are used throughout the WordPress code.

The "Site Address (URL)" setting is the address you want people to type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.
The "WordPress Address (URL)" setting is the address where your WordPress core files reside.

Edit wp-config.php like this

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

and functions.php

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
```

**Important! Do not leave those lines in the functions.php file. 
Remove them after the site is up and running again.**

Comment: Probably you have right.. But, when i do this i get 404 Page Not Found. Because wordpress is inside account directory, not in root. So when i click login url is site.com/login.

Comment: Copying .htaccess from wordpress directory inside .htaccess inside root solve my problem. Of course i change also website url in settings. Thank you,marked as answer.